# How to check if no rows retrieve from command in crystal report?

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

**How to check if  no rows  retrieve from command  in crystal report?**

Answer (score 0):

My solution: [Crystal Reports: Display a Message When Report Has No Data](http://www.cogniza.com/wordpress/2007/08/28/crystal-reports-display-a-message-when-report-has-no-data/)

Answer (score 0):

When do you want to "check" ?

"If you want to catch it in your form, you would need to have some code in the form perform the same query that the report will perform and see if there are any records returned before loading the report. Then you can show your message box and cancel before the report is loaded." - David Stratton (Original thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461289/determine-if-crystal-report-has-no-data-before-showing))

Specifically in the report? See [this article](http://www.cogniza.com/wordpress/2007/08/28/crystal-reports-display-a-message-when-report-has-no-data/)

It seems if you want to do this in the report itself you'll essentially be using the same method you would be in your program, by using a `Count()` of the rows returned.

I think this would be somewhat similar to `HasData` property in VBA.

Here is also another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287759/suppress-crystal-reports-section-if-there-are-no-rows-in-a-datatable) related to what you're asking.

Have you tried anything?